# How to retrieve the xml element attribute name in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I need to retrieve the xml attribute values in asp.net. Here i cant retrieve data from xml. Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this might help you ....

Here is how my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CategoryList>
  <Category>
    <MainCategory ID="1">VC++</MainCategory>
    <Description>A list of VC</Description>
    <Active>Yes</Active>
  </Category>
</CategoryList>
```

add the value of the element MainCategory to the drop down list. I used the `SelectNodes` function to get the values and stored it while iterating through a loop. This looked like this:

```
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/CategoryList/Category");

for(int i=0;i<nodes.Count;i++)
{
    ddlMainCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem(
        nodes.Item(i).ChildNodes[0].InnerText, 
        nodes.Item(i).ChildNodes[0].Attributes["ID"].Value
        ));
}
```